# Check for multiple duplicates in MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I've currently got 3 different queries to check for multiple users in database, I was wondering if there is a way to combine then all in a single query.

Based on email:

```
SELECT 
    user_email,
    COUNT(user_email)
FROM
    users
GROUP BY user_email
HAVING COUNT(user_email) > 1;
```

Based on last name:

```
SELECT 
    user_lastname,
    COUNT(user_lastname)
FROM
    users
GROUP BY user_lastname
HAVING COUNT(user_lastname) > 1;
```

Based on phone:

```
SELECT 
    user_phone,
    COUNT(user_phone)
FROM
    users
GROUP BY user_phone
HAVING COUNT(user_phone) > 1;
```

For each query I am showing a list of email|last name|phone number and the number of multiple users there are.
My final plan is to make a list with just the duplicate users containing just the information they got caught on (for example user X / Y duplicate based on U email etc).

```
User_ID | user_email     | user_firstname | user_lastname | user_phone
1       | snow@asd.com   | John           | Snow          | 123456
2       | user@asd.com   | George         | Smith         | 546632
3       | usr@asd.com    | Maria          | Coal          | 553211
4       | snow@asd.com   | Jack           | Black         | 752210
5       | bin@asd.com    | Tom            | Bing          | 856332
6       | col@asd.com    | Storm          | Snow          | 325412
7       | ding@asd.com   | Mairy          | Call          | 123456
8       | user23@asd.com | Kim            | Loren         | 351200
9       | user44@asd.com | Dot            | Honey         | 546632
10      | user11@asd.com | Jack           | Smithson      | 455871
```

The end result must show users 1+4 (same email) +7 (same phone number with 1) +6 (same last name with 1) + 2+9 (same phone number)

```
User_ID | user_email     | user_firstname | user_lastname | user_phone
1       | snow@asd.com   | John           | Snow          | 123456
4       | snow@asd.com   | Jack           | Black         | 752210
6       | col@asd.com    | Storm          | Snow          | 325412
7       | ding@asd.com   | Mairy          | Call          | 123456
2       | user@asd.com   | George         | Smith         | 546632
9       | user44@asd.com | Dot            | Honey         | 546632
```

Comment: Post some sample data and expected results.

Comment: @forpas I hope that is good enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case I think that EXISTS is the best solution:

```
select u.* from users u
where exists (
  select 1 from users
  where user_id <> u.user_id
  and (user_lastname = u.user_lastname or user_email = u.user_email or user_phone = u.user_phone)
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bT7PRyxu4bU9N6SQD722kc/0).
Results:

```
| User_ID | user_email     | user_firstname | user_lastname | user_phone |
| ------- | -------------- | -------------- | ------------- | ---------- |
| 1       | snow@asd.com   | John           | Snow          | 123456     |
| 2       | user@asd.com   | George         | Smith         | 546632     |
| 4       | snow@asd.com   | Jack           | Black         | 752210     |
| 6       | col@asd.com    | Storm          | Snow          | 325412     |
| 7       | ding@asd.com   | Mairy          | Call          | 123456     |
| 9       | user44@asd.com | Dot            | Honey         | 546632     |
```